# Stringified template argument

Tags: c++, templates, stringification

Is it possible to get a stringified version of a template argument name?

Something like this, if only we were running the preprocessor:

```
template <typename T>
struct Named{
    const char* name(){ return "Named<" #T ">"; }
};
```

**Edit**
Duplicate.  See here
[Stringifying template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488186/stringifying-template-arguments)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stringifying template arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488186/stringifying-template-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The closest thing you can have is `typeid(T).name()`. However, the result of this is unspecified, even an implementation which returned empty strings for all types would be conforming. For debugging purposes it often is sufficient, though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `typeid()` as suggested in [Stringifying template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488186/stringifying-template-arguments) ?

Answer (score 1):

Not without pain. My closest solution:

```
template <typename T>
struct Named{
    const char* name();
};

#define DEFINE_NAMED(T) template<> const char* Named<T>::name(){ return #T ; };

DEFINE_NAMED(SomeNameSpace::SomeClass)
```

Of course, this is evil... 
so far you could use [`gccxml`](http://www.gccxml.org) and `xsltproc` to automatic find unimplemented `Named<T>::name()`, create some auxilary file, compile it, and finally link it:

```
gccxml test.cpp -fxml=test.xml
xsltproc -o Named.cpp Named.xslt test.xml
g++ Named.cpp test.cpp -o test.bin
```

Some proposal Named.xslt file (duno if work):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="Method" >
    <xsl:text>template&lt;&gt; const char* </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@demangled" />
    <xsl:text> { return "</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(@demangled,7,string-length(@demangled)-15)" />
    <xsl:text>"; };
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>#include "Named.h"
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/GCC_XML/Method[matches(@demangled,'^Named.*::name()$') and @extern = '1' ]" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```