# How to get a templated typename as a string?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

The following code prints out the string "T" not the actual typename when the templated function is called. Is there a way to get the real typename without adding anything to the types being templated?

```
#define stringify(a) #a
#define tostring(a) stringify(a)

template <typename T>
void function_foo(T a, T b)
{
    cout << tostring(T) << endl;
    ...
}
```

Comment: dupe: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488186/stringifying-template-arguments

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484982/how-to-convert-typename-t-to-string-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates don't work like that. In your template `T` specifies a type, and not a sequence of tokens:

```
typedef int lolztype;
typedef int lulztype;

function_foo<lolztype>(0, 0);
function_foo<lulztype>(0, 0); // calls the *same* template
```

There is no way to get `lolztype` or `lulztype` respectively. What you could try is using `typeid(T).name()`, but that isn't very helpful because it isn't required to be human readable and not even required to be distinct for each type.

You could try using [geordi's](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/geordi/) file  [`type_strings.hpp`](https://github.com/Eelis/geordi/blob/master/prelude/type_strings.hpp), which can print out a human readable string when compiled with GCC.

Comment: do you mean that two types that may have identical internal binary representation, but distinct definitions/declarations might have the same typeid().name() ?

Comment: @Stephane it's completely unspecified.

Comment: @Stephane: he means that (for example) `int` and `std::vector<double>` might have the same `type_info::name()`.

Comment: okay, so there's no garanty of interesting result depending on the implementation of the compiler.

Comment: @StephaneRolland As a programmer, you usually try to stay away from "interesting" results :) Myself, I would find it pretty interesting if `int` and `std::vector<double>` _did_ have the same `type_info::name()`.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Interesting? In which way? Maybe you mean delighting, funny, curious, for a few seconds maybe. At most :)

Comment: @StephaneRolland What I mean is, if someone says that a result is _interesting_, it probably means that the result was unexpected. If you expected the result, why would it be interesting? Personally, I wouldn't expect `int` and `std::vector<double>` to have the same `type_info::name()`, so if they did I would find that interesting.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void function_foo(T a, T b)
{
    cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;
    ...
}
```

what typeid().name() returns is plateform dependent but is a string may represent your type.

Comment: This is actually technically incorrect. From [the manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/name/):

"Returns a null-terminated character sequence that may identify the type.".

So it may or may not actually "represent your type".

Comment: @ChrisKitching If the string can be used to identify the type, doesn't it technically represent the type?

Comment: @ChrisKitching I have been told several times not to refer to www.cplusplus.com documentation which may not be of optimal quality. Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name .

Answer (score 1):

There's the `typeid` operator.  But note that the `name()` string is implementation-defined.  In particular, it often involves some name mangling.  Some implementations also provide another public method to get a "prettier" string; check your `<typeinfo>` header.

```
#include <typeinfo>
template <typename T>
void function_foo(T a, T b)
{
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your only choice is to define this reflection on your own, perhaps via an interface that returns the string representation of its concrete type.

```
struct my_type : public reflects {
    my_type();
    static const std::string& type_name = "my_type";
};
```