# find out the type of auto

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, generic-lambda

I am playing with generic lambda in C++1y and I often confused by don't know what is the type of `auto` variable/parameter. Is any good way to find it out?

Currently I am using `typeid(decltype(arg)).name())` but it is not very useful. [@encode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) gives a slightly better result but still hard to decipher it

example:

```
auto f = [](auto && a, auto b) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(a)).name() << std::endl << @encode(decltype(a)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(b)).name() << std::endl << @encode(decltype(b)) << std::endl;
};

int i = 1;
f(i, i);
f(1, 1);
f(std::make_unique<int>(2), std::make_unique<int>(2));
auto const ptr = std::make_unique<int>();
f(ptr, nullptr);
```

output

```
i  // it does not tell me it is reference
^i // ^ means pointer, but it is actually reference, kinda pointer though
i
i

i
^i
i
i

NSt3__110unique_ptrIiNS_14default_deleteIiEEEE
^{unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >={__compressed_pair<int *, std::__1::default_delete<int> >=^i}}
NSt3__110unique_ptrIiNS_14default_deleteIiEEEE
{unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >={__compressed_pair<int *, std::__1::default_delete<int> >=^i}}

NSt3__110unique_ptrIiNS_14default_deleteIiEEEE
r^{unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >={__compressed_pair<int *, std::__1::default_delete<int> >=^i}}
Dn
*
```

I mainly want is to know that is the parameter a lvalue ref/rvalue ref/passed by value etc.

and I am using Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488186/stringifying-template-arguments

Comment: `@encode` is not C++. Are you writing C++, or Objective-C++? `^ means pointer, but it is actually reference, kinda pointer though` No, it means something _quite_ different.

Comment: Have you tried using the type-traits to get information about the type? Like for example [`std::is_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference)? See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) for a full list.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes it is Objective-C++. `.mm` file. but from my experience, `@encode` works for most of the C++ class (not for very complex templates class)

Comment: @BryanChen: They are two different languages, so your question is tagged incorrectly. Please fix.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes it will be my last resort

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I actually want C++ answer. Because ObjC++ is superset of C++ so I can use it for ObjC++ code.

Comment: However, doing checks of the type is often a sign of bad design. You might want to check your design. Also, you might want to read [about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because you have a solution you want to use but need help implementing it but you're not telling us what kind of problem you actually want to solve with your solution. There may be other, even better, solutions to your original problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't have original problem. I am learning how generic lambda works. I can read standard but I want to learn it from code.

Comment: This is more YX.  Or maybe Rx.  Would you believe XYZ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what I have ended up with. combined with [@Konrad Rudolph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23266701/642626) and @Joachim Pileborg's comment

```
std::string demangled(std::string const& sym) {
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)>
    name{abi::__cxa_demangle(sym.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr), std::free};
    return {name.get()};
}

template <class T>
void print_type() {
    bool is_lvalue_reference = std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value;
    bool is_rvalue_reference = std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value;
    bool is_const = std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value;

    std::cout << demangled(typeid(T).name());
    if (is_const) {
        std::cout << " const";
    }
    if (is_lvalue_reference) {
        std::cout << " &";
    }
    if (is_rvalue_reference) {
        std::cout << " &&";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    auto f = [](auto && a, auto b) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        print_type<decltype(a)>();
        print_type<decltype(b)>();
    };

    const int i = 1;
    f(i, i);
    f(1, 1);
    f(std::make_unique<int>(2), std::make_unique<int>(2));
    auto const ptr = std::make_unique<int>();
    f(ptr, nullptr);

}
```

and output

```
int const &
int

int &&
int

std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > &&
std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >

std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > const &
std::nullptr_t
```

Comment: Hmm. Why is `type_helper` a class rather than a function template?

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes it should be function template... I was trying to do it differently but end up with this. updated now

Comment: I'm sure I'm just missing the right header, but having trouble find which one searching for this error:  `print_type_inferred_by_auto.cpp:24:10: error: ‘abi’ has not been declared
     name{abi::__cxa_demangle(sym.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr), std::free};`.  I also get this error:  `print_type_inferred_by_auto.cpp:24:80: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unique_ptr<char, void (*)(void*)>::unique_ptr(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
     name{abi::__cxa_demangle(sym.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr), std::free};`  I have C++11 compiler.  Is this C++14?

Answer (score 4):

Use GCC’s [`__cxa_demangle`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) function:

```
std::string demangled(std::string const& sym) {
    std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)>
        name{abi::__cxa_demangle(sym.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr), std::free};
    return {name.get()};
}

auto f = [](auto && a, auto b) {
    std::cout << demangled(typeid(decltype(a)).name()) << '\n';
    std::cout << demangled(typeid(decltype(b)).name()) << '\n';
};
```

Comment: thanks. it is very useful to decipher `NSt3__110unique_ptrIiNS_14default_deleteIiEEEE` into `std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >` but it doesn't help me to know whether it is reference or not

Comment: You know, language-linkage might prevent assigning `std::free` to a pointer of type `void(*)(void*)`: Better use a lambda. Or define your own policy `struct default_free`.

Comment: @Deduplicator `std::free` doesn’t have language linkage in C++. See §20.2 and §23.10.12. But if language linkage were an issue you could declare your function pointer type accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure what in [utility] you want to Point out. [containers] is 23.10, but there's no 23.10.12...

Comment: To add to that, a Paragraph from [using.linkage]: "*Whether a name from the C standard library declared with external linkage has `extern "C"` or `extern "C++"` linkage is implementation-deﬁned. It is recommended that an implementation use `extern "C++"` linkage for this purpose.179*" And the referenced note: "*179) The only reliable way to declare an object or function signature from the Standard C library is by including the header that declares it, notwithstanding the latitude granted in 7.1.4 of the C Standard.*"

Comment: @Deduplicator In my version (N4713, compiled 2018-01-16) the section numbers refer to [library.c] and [c.malloc]. The section you quote presumably refers to `::free` etc, *not* `std::free` (which, as part of the C++ standard library, is referred to in the preceding paragraph). That said, this part of the standard could benefit from a clarification.

Comment: But it is unspecified whether the name is first declared in global scope and then imported into `std`, so it *does* refer to `std::clibraryfunction()` too.

Comment: @Deduplicator I read this differently: Yes, you’re right, this is unspecified. But my reading is that *if* the implementation imports the global functions into `std`, then it needs to nevertheless somehow ensure their C++ linkage. Otherwise, the declarations shown in [c.malloc] (etc) would be incomplete, and [library.c] seems to indicate that this would be explicitly marked in the standard document.

Answer (score 0):

> I mainly want is to know that is the parameter a lvalue ref/rvalue ref/passed by value etc.

Well this is easy.

```
template<class T>
struct is_lvalue:std::false_type {};
template<class T>
struct is_lvalue<T&>:std::true_type {};
template<class T>
struct is_literal:std::true_type {};
template<class T>
struct is_literal<T&&>:std::false_type {};
template<class T>
struct is_literal<T&>:std::false_type {};// I do not think needed
```

just do a `is_lvalue<decltype(x)>::value` and `is_value<decltype(x)>::value`.

An `rvalue` (temporary or moved reference) is a non-literal non-lvalue.

Comment: any reason to reimplement `std::is_lvalue_reference` and `std::is_rvalue_reference`?

Comment: @bryanchen Other than the possibility that your `std` library was lacking it, nope.