# Getting lambda arguments types inside function is not working

Tags: c++, c++11

A follow up question regarding [Is it possible to figure out the parameter type and return type of a lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda). I tested the code and it works fine for me but only when I call it from `main()`, when I call the code from `Do` the code does not compile, please let me know if you can uncomment the lines in `Do` function and compile the code

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
std::string GetTypeName()
{
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266391/find-out-the-type-of-auto/23266701#23266701
  std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> name{abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), 0, 0, nullptr), std::free};
  return name.get();
}

template <typename T>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
{
    enum { arity = sizeof...(Args) };

    typedef ReturnType result_type;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
    };
};

template <typename FuncType>
void Do(FuncType func)
{
  typedef function_traits<decltype(func)> traits;
  //typename traits::arg<1>::type x = 0;
  std::cout << GetTypeName<traits>() << std::endl;
  //std::cout << GetTypeName<traits::arg<1>::type>() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  auto func = [] (int x, float y, double z) -> void { };
  Do(func);
  typedef function_traits<decltype(func)> traits;
  traits::arg<1>::type x = 0;
  std::cout << GetTypeName<traits>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << GetTypeName<traits::arg<1>::type>() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The compilation error is

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void Do(FuncType)’:
test.cpp:37:20: error: non-template ‘arg’ used as template
   typename traits::arg<1>::type x = 0;
                    ^
test.cpp:37:20: note: use ‘traits::template arg’ to indicate that it is a template
test.cpp:37:20: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
```

I use `g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)`, the compilation command is `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test`

Comment: As usual when posting questions about build errors, you should tell us the errors you get. Copy (as text) the full and complete output of the compiler and/or linker, and paste it inside the question body. Since that's missing http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: **TL;DR**: `typename traits::template arg<1>::type x = 0;`

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller for some reason, this is a c++ syntax I always forget

Comment: All part of the joy of C++, for everyone, not just you. At least compilers are good at hinting. The note under the error tries to be helpful.